# PHP Session Variables not working if we set them in if conditions

Tags: php, session

I am working on implementing OAUTH2.0 authentication using php. I have the following piece of code got from internet.

```
// Start the login process by sending the user to Github's authorization page
if(get('action') == 'login') {
  unset($_SESSION['access_token']);
  unset($_SESSION['access_token_postman']);

  if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'])){
    $_SESSION['access_token_postman'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'];
  }

  // Generate a random hash and store in the session for security
  $_SESSION['state'] = hash('sha256', microtime(TRUE).rand().$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

  $params = array(
    'client_id' => OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID,
    'redirect_uri' => OAUTH2_REDIRECT_URI,
    'scope' => 'user',
    'state' => $_SESSION['state']
  );
  // Redirect the user to Github's authorization page
  header('Location: ' . $authorizeURL . '?' . http_build_query($params));
  die();
}
```

I have initialized the session using session_start(); at the top.

But the problem I am facing is, I am not able to access the $_SESSION['access_token_postman'] after the if condition. I know that the value is set with in the if condition as I am able to print it with in if condition.

The same problem is with $_SESSION['state'] also. I am not able to access the session after if condition.

Can someone let me know what mistake I am doing?

Thanks.

Comment: Where are you *trying* to access the value after the `if`?  Can you provide a minimal but complete example to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: I am trying to access it after "if(get('action') == 'login')" condition. I am calling the url something like http://www.example.com/test/login which will take it to the if condition but after the if condition, I am not able to access the sessions that were set.

Comment: According to the code shown if that `if` block is executed then the result is a redirect header and a call to `die()`.  No code after a call to `die()` will be executed.  If you want code after your `if` block to execute, don't redirect the user and terminate the script.